# Qt :: Нужно событие изменение размера контента главного окна

Tags: qt

Всем здравствуйте. Нужно событие изменение размера контента главного окна. Хочу вставить изображение в `QLabel`, на всё окно, но каждое изображение имеет разные размеры, поэтому мне нужно событие изменения контента, чтобы я мог использовать `setFixedSize(sizeHint())`

Comment: Модет быть `resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)` подойдёт?